# How to handle missing data in a small sample

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation, case-cohort

We've conducted a cohort research (single group), with 30 subjects. The study is an observational study, with two measurements (at the beginning and at the end of the study period). 5 of them were lost to follow-up, due to technical issues.

***editing: I elaborate regarding the "technical issues", as it seems to be the key for the question. The subjects left our organization, and therefore our ethical committee did not allow us to evaluate them again. 
ALL of our subjects left the organization due to the medical issue that we investigated. They all left two months after a certain time point (that was prior to inclusion in the study - they were included due to this procedure. therefore, we knew that ALL of our subjects will leave the organization). Unfortunately, some were missed by us, and we contacted them few days after they left. If we were reaching them few days earlier, we could have include them in the study.

I'm wondering if should I impute their data. On the one hand, 5/30 is a relatively large amount of data which is missing. On the other hand, any imputation that I will perform will only decrease the sample variability, or will exaggerate the effect that is found on the 25 subjects.

What do you think is the best method to handle this situation?

Comment: If it was technical issues, are they not missing completely at random, rather than missing at random?

Comment: What was the nature of the "technical issue"?

Comment: @AdamO
The subjects left our organization, and therefore our ethical committee did not allow us to evaluate them again.

Comment: @UriGottlieb withdrawal is generally considered informative censoring.

Comment: @AdamO, OK - thank you for your comment!

Comment: Could you please add this new information as an edit to the original post? Not everybody reads comments ...

Comment: If they disproportionately left due to retirement, then that would affect the age distribution, which may be relevant depending on your research subject.